# PickerView - How to return 2 different array based on a segmented Control selection

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app I have a text field (Distance) that has segmented control to choose the unit reference (Km/Mi):

[image]

I have another text field (pace) that show a UIPickerView. This picker view can be populated with 2 arrays based on what unit the user selected. Everything works except that, even when the picker view is not shown and I change the selection, the array change only when I start scroll the picker view. So initially it shows the array in km even if I selected Mi and then it changes when I start moving the picker.

Initially I set a variable for the unit reference and the 2 arrays

```
var unitReference = "Km" // this is the initial selection on the segmented control 
let paceKmArray = [" ", "Relaxing(less than 15km/h)", "Easy(15km/h-20km/h)","Medium(20km/h-25km/h)","Nice(25km/h-30km/h)","Fast(30km/h-35km/h)", "Very Fast(>35km/h)"]
let paceMiArray = [" ", "Relaxing(less than 10 mi/h)", "Easy(10mi/h-13mi/h)","Medium(13mi/h-16mi/h))","Nice(16mi/h-19mi/h))","Fast(19mi/h-12mi/h))", "Very Fast(>22mi/h)"]
```

then in `viewDidLoad`

```
unitReferenceSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "unitChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged);
```

which call this method to changed the unit reference

```
func unitChanged(sender:UISegmentedControl){

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
        unitReference = "Km"
        print(unitReference)

    }

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

        unitReference = "Mi"

        print(unitReference)    
    }
}
```

And the picker view methods

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView.tag == 0{
        return rideTypeArray[row]
    }

    if pickerView.tag == 1{
        if unitReference == "Km"{

        return paceKmArray[row]
        }
        if unitReference == "Mi"{

         return paceMiArray[row]
        }
    }

        return ""

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

    if pickerView.tag == 0{

    return rideTypeArray.count
    }
    if pickerView.tag == 1{

        if self.unitReference == "Km"{

            return paceKmArray.count
        }
        if self.unitReference == "Mi"{

            return paceMiArray.count
        }


    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{

    if pickerView.tag == 0{
        rideTypeTextField.text = rideTypeArray[rideTypePickerView!.selectedRowInComponent(0)] as String   

    }

    if pickerView.tag == 1{

        if unitReference == "Km"{

            paceTextField.text = paceKmArray[pacePickerView!.selectedRowInComponent(0)] as String
        }
        if unitReference == "Mi"{

            paceTextField.text = paceMiArray[pacePickerView!.selectedRowInComponent(0)] as String
        }     

    }

}
```

I am not sure this is the best way to do it. If there is a more elegant way to do it, I will be more than happy to learn it.

Comment: If i have to do this, i would take a third array and treat this as the single datasource while switching between `paceKmArray` and `paceMiArray` upon segment selection.

Comment: @Gandalf thanks,  I also \tried to do that but the behaviour didn't change

Comment: You are not calling `reloadAllComponents` on your picker when you change the segment selection. Call it from `unitChanged:` as last line.

Comment: of course!!!  ;-) it works perfectly now! If you answer I will selected it. I added `pacePickerView.reloadAllComponents()` to the `unitChanged` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing the changes in your picker view because you are not reloading the data after the datasource is changed. Just call `reloadAllComponents` on your `pickerView` once you have changed the datasource and you are good to go.

```
func unitChanged(sender:UISegmentedControl) {
    //Your previous code for changing the datasource array.

    //Now reload the UIPickerView
    pacePickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

One more suggestion i would like to give is that if in both the datasource array's have same set of key value pairs then you should keep a 3rd array as the ultimate datasource and switch it with the respective arrays from your `unitChanged:` method. That way you won't need to have an `if` condition every now and then to get the current set of data.